# How to access MicroStack VM instance from external network

Tags: openstack, microstack

I have installed MicroStack and started a Cirros instance as it is described in [MicroStack docs](https://microstack.run/docs/). Everything works as expected. The Cirros instance at `10.20.20.202:22` is available from the host where MicroStack is installed.
The host IP/LAN is `192.168.56.103/24`.

However, MicroStack install created a virtual network interface br-ex with IP `10.20.20.1` and the network `10.20.20.0/24` is used as external network in MicroStack/OpenStack, which is available only from the host. I thought that external network and floating IPs should be on a physical interface of the host so that the floating IPs are accessible from 'outside', that is, floating IPs should be from `192.168.56.103/24`.

How could I access instances with floating IP from other computers than the host MicroStack is installed on?

Comment: Would you care to share the answer please, I'm having the same issue, even after adding an ip route which forwards from 10.20.20.0 to my host's IP address, I still cannot access the cirros image through SSH directly, without doing an SSH proxy by accessing to my host machine via ssh and then to the cirros instance using ssh.

Comment: @Rafik (sorry for the late answer) I have not found any solutions maybe because microstack got out of scope in my case

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to the same problem today and found I had to add a static route via my Hyper-V virtual switch address.

So for me `route add 10.20.20.0/24 172.20.192.1` allowed me to access OpenStack from my Windows machine while Ubuntu/Microstack was running inside a VM.

Comment: Hi @Dan, is 172.20.192.1 the ip of the network interface which Ubuntu/Microstack (running in a VM) communicates with your Windows host through? If so, then yes, it is working, if ip_forward is set on Ubuntu/Microstack, floating IP-s are available from your Windows host. 

However, if we imagine that Ubuntu/Microstack is not installed inside a VM but on a physical machine, then in my understanding, the floating IPs should be available from any machine one the physical LAN of Ubunty/Microstack (which is not really applicable in the case Microstack is installed inside a VM).