# Change the 10.20.20.1 network to my VMware network

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, vmware, openstack

I installed MicroStack in Ubuntu for the virtual machine. My instance floating IP is 10.20.20.238. I want to access my instance from Windows cmd，only can ping 172.21.10.13, but can't ping 10.20.20.238，so I want to change the 10.20.20.1 network to my own network. What should I do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhAca.png)

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow is about code development, not IT management. serverfault.com would be a more appropriate forum, or perhaps superuser.com.

microstack "fakes" the external network. It's not really external, but only exists on `br-ex`, the external bridge. It doesn't look like you can create a microstack cloud with a different external network CIDR, but you can try adding a subnet to the external network, inserting `ens33` in `br-ex` and adding IP address 172.21.10.13 to `br-ex` . I have not tried this.

However, if your only requirement is to access the instance from the PC, you can [create a tunnel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1276698/how-to-replace-microstack-external-network-10-20-20-0-24-to-our-own-lan-ip-sub) or [add a route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63140567/how-to-access-microstack-vm-instance-from-external-network). What makes sense in your case depends on the virtual machine hypervisor you are using (yours seems to be VMware - I can't comment on that) and the operating system on which this hypervisor runs.