# Communicate the openstack with other existing server

Tags: openstack

I have deployed `Openstack` in Ubuntu server using this link.
(https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/microstack-get-started...)
The installation was successful.
Now, what I want is to communicate the `openstack` with my other existing server.
Can anybody help me in that.
Also, how can I change the `openstack` logo with my project.

[image]

Comment: I think you want this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63140567/how-to-access-microstack-vm-instance-from-external-network.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use openstack horizon?
When I looked at the code from Inspect, the logo on the login page used this code.
[login page code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZLiM.png)

The logo on the Home page uses this code.
[home page code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9H40.png)

How about modifying the "logo.svg" and "logo-splash.svg" files in the "horizon/openstack_dashboard/static/dashboard/img/" location to fit your project?

Comment: I am using Microstack service, link is mentioned above. I have tried to change the images but i think it's a permission issue. Can you tell me how to solve the restriction issue. Thanks in advance